# How to search (Filter) in a JQGrid by Jquery in cshtml file in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am new to jquery and also web development and jqgrid. I am trying to implement "filter" or "Search any column values in JQGrid using Jquery.

The code is beow. Could someone pease assist me how to implement the filter by the 5 column values below?

```
<script>

        $(function() {
              $.ajax({
                cache: false, 
                url: "@Url.Action("GetMovies", "Home")",  
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    $("#list2").jqGrid(
                    {
                        datatype: "local",
                        colNames: ['MovieId', 'Title', 'Genre','ReleaseDate','Classification'],
                        colModel:
                        [
                            { name: 'MovieId', index: 'MovieId', width: 30},
                            { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 190 },
                            { name: 'Genre', index: 'Genre', width: 130 },
                            { name: 'ReleaseDate', index: 'ReleaseDate', width: 100 },
                            { name: 'Classification', index: 'Classification', width: 130 }
                        ],
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30,40],
                        pager: '#pager2',
                        sortname: 'MovieId', sortorder: "asc",
                        viewrecords: true, loadonce: true,
                        caption: "MoVies Collections",
                        findByName:"Title"
                    });

                    $("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: true, add: true, del: false });
                    $("#list2").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager2", { addParams: { position: "last" } });

                    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++)
                        $("#list2").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, result[i]);

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jqGrid "`Toolbar`" search or set `search:true` in '`navGrid`'

```
$("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: true, add: true, del: false,search:true });
```

A small `search icon` will be displayed on left side in bottom.

Or we can have `toolbar search.`

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: true});
```

if you don't want search for particular column set `'search:false'` in `colModel`

See sample demos under 'Searching' tab.

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

For more jqGrid options, check below link.

[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

Comment: @malam: Thank you very much malkam, I used toolbar search, it worked:)

Comment: @malam: I have also seking guidance for Adding and Editing the rows in this grid, I have asked a separate question in our forum just few mins back, could you please help me :(

Comment: Let me check and try:)